# Is there a way to print individual words from a .txt file without leaving out lines?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string readFileToString(string fileName) {
    fstream file;
    string word;
    string returnMe;
    returnMe.resize(200);
    file.open(fileName.c_str());
    while (file >> word) { 
        returnMe += word + " ";
    }
    file.close();
    return returnMe;
}

int main() {
    string fileName = "example.txt";
    cout << readFileToString(fileName);
}
```

I have this code but I have several lines in my txt file and it completely ignores them.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] (which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives) and specify exactly the input, intended output and actual output.

Comment: What is the point of the line `returnMe.resize(200);`? Did you intend to write `reserve` instead of `resize`?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this was, that means changing `fstream file; file.open(fileName.c_str());` to `fstream file(fileName.c_str());`. Or just `fstream file(fileName);` -- there's an overloaded constructor that takes `std::string`. And since the file is used only for input, it should be `ifstream file(fileName);`. Also, you don't need to call `file.close();`; the destructor will do that.

Comment: After your most recent edit, you still have not fully addressed my first comment. The code now seems to be complete, but you still did not specify exactly the input, intended output and the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to print out all the words in the text file then you can use the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>


int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputFile("input.txt");
    std::string word, line;
    if(inputFile)
    {
        while(std::getline(inputFile, line)) //go line by line
        {
            //std::cout<<line<<std::endl; //this prints the line 
            
            std::istringstream ss(line);
            while(ss >> word) //go word by word 
            {
                std::cout << word << std::endl;    
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "File cannot be opened" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/NIP3g8gco).